# How to update certain tuples after deletion in a table

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I am trying to model a music streaming service data base in SQLite and I want to create this trigger: When a song is deleted from a playlist, every song that came after it needs to have its position decremented. I'm not really sure how to write this trigger.

Here is an example of the playlist's table (Sorry for the portuguese names. idMusica = Song ID; posicao = song's position in the playlist)

[image: Playlists]

To further explain what I want here's an example:
If I delete song 6 from playlist 1, the position of song 11 would become 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following will do as you wish :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS playlistreorder 
    AFTER DELETE ON playlist
    BEGIN
        UPDATE playlist SET posicao = posicao -1 WHERE posicao > old.posicao AND idPlayList = old.idPlayList;
    END
;
```

- Note that the table names has been assumed to be playlist

## Example

Consider the following test :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS playlist;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlist (idMusica INTEGER, idPlayList INTEGER, posicao INTEGER);
INSERT INTO playlist (idMusica,idPlayList, posicao) VALUES
    (12,1,1),(5,1,2),(6,1,3),(11,1,4),
    (1,2,1),(2,2,2),(3,2,2),(4,2,4),(9,2,5)
;

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS playlistreorder 
    AFTER DELETE ON playlist
    BEGIN
        UPDATE playlist SET posicao = posicao -1 WHERE posicao > old.posicao AND idPlayList = old.idPlayList;
    END
;
SELECT * FROM playlist;
DELETE FROM playlist WHERE posicao = 3 AND idplayList = 1;
SELECT * FROM playlist;
```

## Example results

### Before reorder (1st Query) :-

[image]

### After reorder (2nd Query) :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that this approach is fundamentally wrong and overly fragile. Instead of tracking the *absolute* position in a playlist, track the *relative* position. That way you don't have to update positions when inserting or deleting songs:

If the first three songs have `posicao` values of 1,2,3, and you want to add a song at position 2, instead of updating the current 2 to 3, the current 3 to 4 and so on, use a new value halfway between the current 1 and 2 position's `posicao`'s: 1.5 in this case.

When deleting, don't worry about filling in the gap; the `posicao`'s on either side of the deleted song are still in the right order.

If you need the absolute position for some reason, you can calculate it in a `SELECT` on the fly with modern versions of sqlite (3.25 or newer) with something like

```
SELECT idMusica, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY posicao) AS pos
FROM playlist_songs
WHERE idPlaylist = :playlistid
ORDER BY posicao
```

or by just incrementing a counter in your program every time you fetch a row froma  given playlist as long as it's ordered by `posicao`.

Window function based queries for inserting into the middle of a playlist and deleting, given an absolute position (Though for deleting, if your junction table isn't a `WITHOUT ROWID` one, it's easier to track the rowid of the songs in your program and delete using the one for the selected song):

```
INSERT INTO playlist_songs(idMusica, idPlaylist, posicao)
VALUES(:songid, :playlistid
     , (SELECT (pos + prev_pos) / 2.0
        FROM (SELECT posicao AS pos
                   , lag(posicao, 1, 0.0) OVER (ORDER BY posicao) AS prev_pos
                   , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY posicao) AS rn
              FROM playlist_songs WHERE idPlaylist = :playlistid)
        WHERE rn = :position));

DELETE FROM playlist_songs
WHERE rowid = (SELECT rowid
               FROM (SELECT rowid, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY posicao) AS rn
                     FROM playlist_songs WHERE idPlaylist = :playlistid)
               WHERE rn = :position);
```